# escape special characters ~ and / in sql server query

Tags: sql, search, escaping

I want to Escape SPecial character ~ and /.

My Barcode in the text box will be as:  **~~~671524055212/**     but I want to search it as  **671524055212**

How to remove these special characters?

What I'm using currently is this , which does not work.

```
        SELECT  LocalSKU,ItemName,QOH,Price,Integer2,Integer3 FROM Inventory where Barcode LIKE '%671524055212%' escape '/'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

SELECT  LocalSKU,ItemName,QOH,Price,Integer2,Integer3 FROM Inventory where Barcode LIKE '%671524055212%'